# Getting error nested javascript filter property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
var Posts = [
  {
    likes: ['5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c8c'],
    _id: '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7c',
    width: 473,
    height: 1000
  },
  {
    likes: ['5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c6d'],
    _id: '5e5782e7f695d70b6e376c82',
    width: 601,
    height: 1000
  }
];
const myId = '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c8c';
const result = Posts.likes.filter(userId => userId.toString() !== myId.toString());
console.log("full", result);
```

Getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined may be cause of nested filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is `Posts` is an array and thus `Posts.likes` returns `undefined` and thus you get this error. To fix this, you will simply need to apply the `.filter()` method on `Posts` array itself and then destructure the object for each item in the array and just get `likes` property from it and then match `likes[0]` with passed `myId` variable like:

```js
var Posts = [{
    likes: ['5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c8c'],
    _id: '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7c',
    width: 473,
    height: 1000
  },
  {
    likes: ['5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c6d'],
    _id: '5e5782e7f695d70b6e376c82',
    width: 601,
    height: 1000
  }
];
const myId = '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c8c';
const result = Posts.filter(({likes}) => likes[0] !== myId.toString());
console.log("full", result);
```